# fetching data from 2 collections in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below mentioned db structure where users master data is saving in `users` collection and images is saving in `users_slug` collection, I am saving `users` collection node key as a reference in `users_slug` collection So basically I will have one master collection and many child collections so I need to get all the child's data based on masters table records node key (basically one to many relationship) where I can perform CRUD operation on child table based on masters node key.

I have 2 queries ....

**1) Below mentioned db structure is good approach or not? (Because I am new to firebase, and I searched a lot but didn't find anything related to it )**

**2) How can I perform fetch on both the collection based on node key ?**

```
{
    "users": {
        "-LSDmLO1GyfbumPZPopb": {
            "first_name": "test",
            "gender": "M",
            "last_name": "test123",
            "username": "test123"
    }
  },
  "users_slug": {
        "-LSDmLgLW9KgTg1BpsxX": [
            {
                "new_file_name": "5bfb97e92dbde.jpg",
                "original_file_name": "128483.1.jpg",
                "user_id": "-LSDmLO1GyfbumPZPopb"
            },
            {
                "new_file_name": "5bfb97e92dd09.jpg",
                "original_file_name": "amit.jpg",
                "user_id": "-LSDmLO1GyfbumPZPopb"
            },
            {
                "new_file_name": "5bfb97e92dd45.jpeg",
                "original_file_name": "download.jpeg",
                "user_id": "-LSDmLO1GyfbumPZPopb"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more info on which exact queries you want to be able to execute. This has an influence on your NoSQL data model. For example, if you want to query all the image related to a user you denormalize your data in such a way you would be able to do it in one query.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i have updated my question and tried to brief the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

(If I understand correctly your needs) you could denormalize your data like the following, by duplicating the `slug` data of each user under each `user` node.

This way you only need one query to get all the "slugs" of a given user.

You may keep the `users_slug` node (i.e. "collection" to use the vocabulary of your post) if you need to make some specific queries. (For example queries to the `-LSDmLgLW9KgTg1BpsxX` node -or to future siblings-, but it is not clear what is this uniqueId).

Denormalizing is quite common in NoSQL world and you should not hesitate to duplicate your data, in order to optimize your queries. Note that to simultaneously write to two (or more) nodes, in order to manage data consistency, you can use the `update()` method, see the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update).

```
{
    "users": {
        "-LSDmLO1GyfbumPZPopb": {
            "first_name": "test",
            "gender": "M",
            "last_name": "test123",
            "username": "test123"
            "slugs": {
                 "-LSDmLgLW9KgTg1BpsxX": [
                            {
                                "new_file_name": "5bfb97e92dbde.jpg",
                                "original_file_name": "128483.1.jpg"
                            },
                            {
                                "new_file_name": "5bfb97e92dd09.jpg",
                                "original_file_name": "amit.jpg"
                            },
                            ....
                  ]

    }
  },
  "users_slug": {
        "-LSDmLgLW9KgTg1BpsxX": [
            {
                "new_file_name": "5bfb97e92dbde.jpg",
                "original_file_name": "128483.1.jpg",
                "user_id": "-LSDmLO1GyfbumPZPopb"
            },
            ..........
        ]
    }
}
```

Finally, you may watch this official Firebase video series about "The Firebase Database For SQL Developers" https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s and in particular the 6th video on denormalization https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&index=7&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&t=0s

Comment: how to I fetch data from this collection by '-LSEufUsgTiWMESbAZfO' ID?        

Array
(
    [-LSEufnnC_fTx1svGGv8] => Array
        (
            [slug_node_key] => -LSEufdEJ_d4ZhnqbUJA
            [user_node_key] => -LSEufUsgTiWMESbAZfO
        )

)

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean. You may be more precise on which exact queries you want to execute, independently of the initial data model. E.g. all users with a certain slug? all slugs for a user? etc.

Comment: i just want to filter data from 2 collection based on node key which is primary key in one collection and reference key in another collection